# SQLite IF ELSE query for Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to do something similar to this:

```
IF id = 3 AND time = '12/1/2016'
    UPDATE visits SET status = 1 WHERE id = 3
ELSE IF id = 3 AND time != '12/1/2016'
    DELETE FROM visits WHERE id = 3
```

I have `id` and `time`, if both matches update a field of row having this `id`, if `id` matches but `time` does not match delete row having this `id`. How would you do that?

Comment: Had a similar problem, this helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3881562/3260244

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["if, then, else" in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881330/if-then-else-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: Use these two statements

```
UPDATE visits SET status = 1
WHERE id = 3 AND time = '12/1/2016';

DELETE FROM visits
WHERE id = 3 AND time != '12/1/2016';
```

Comment: Good solution, though I was looking for single query

Comment: `CASE WHEN...THEN` Statement cannot be used here in my opinion, as you need two operations and it cannot handle both of them in one command.